# Как удалить сообщение бота Telegram JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-telegram-bot-api

Мне нужно удалить сообщение бота, проблема в том, что id этого сообщения не получается вычислить, кроме использования этого метода. Не могли бы вы, пожалуйста, подсказать, каким образом можно удалить сообщение бота?

```js
bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'How to delete message?').then((result) => {setTimeout(() => {bot.deleteMessage(msg.chat.id, result.message_id)}, 1000)}).catch(err => console.log(err))
```